# Facebook Feed API is behaving strangely

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are using Facebook Graph API v5.0, we have seen errors for some customers while calling the User Feed API.

This is happening for only a few customers while other the API returns data.

{"error":{"message":"(#10) This endpoint requires the 'manage_pages' or 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"fbtrace_id":"A29lzW8U9XGdaFvAI3P_xE5"}}

API= https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/134502139957?fields=id,name,link,feed.fields(id,message,attachments,story,properties,created_time,to,from,message_tags,place,privacy).since(1621872358).until(1621958758).limit(100)

The interesting thing is: if we remove the field "from" from the API and make calls using the same token, we are able to get the response.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is happening because the `from` is a _page_ for at least one of the posts, and page data is generally only accessible any more, if you either have admin access to the page, or gotten your app approved for the one of the mentioned features.

Comment: I suppose Facebook could handle this a bit more gracefully, by returning some sort of placeholder/dummy data for `from` in these cases, instead of making the whole query fail. Maybe file a bug report and ask them to implement a better way of handling this.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your reply. Here is another interesting behavior.
That particular epoch timestamp in the above API query:
1621872358 = > Monday, May 24, 2021 4:05:58 PM
1621958758 = > Tuesday, May 25, 2021 4:05:58 PM

Now, if we query from May 24 to May 26, it worked so thinking that it could not be permission issue. Let me know about your thoughts on this.